# Force update Amazon CloudFront on iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using Amazon S3 in conjunction with Amazon CloudFront, basically in my app I have a method to update an S3 object, basically I get the S3 object using CloudFront, I make a change to the data and I reupload it under the same key -- basically replacing/updating the file/object.

However, CloudFront doesn't seem to update along with S3 (well it does, but my users don't have all day), is there a way to force a CloudFront content update? Apparently you can invalidate it, is there an iOS SDK way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that there is a way to make an CloudFront invalidation request via the iOS SDK. You would likely need to build your own method to formulate the request against AWS API.

I would however suggest that you take another approach. Invalidation requests are expensive operations (relative to other Cloudfront costs).  You probably do not want to leave it up to your user to be able to initiate an unlimited amount of invalidation requests against CloudFront via the application.  You will also run up against limits to the number of concurrent invalidation requests you can have.  Your best best is to actually implement a file name versioning scheme to where you can change the file name in a programmatic way for each revision.  You would then reference the new URL in Cloudfront with each revision, eliminating the need to wait for a cache refresh or perform an invalidation.  Also this will lead to more immediate response availability for the image, as invalidation requests may take a while to process.

Please note the following from the CloudFront FAQ:

> Q. Is there a limit to the number of invalidation requests I can make?
>       There are no limits on the total number of files you can invalidate; however, each invalidation request you make can have a maximum of 1,000 files. In addition, you can only have 3 invalidation requests in progress at any given time. If you exceed this limit, further invalidation requests will receive an error response until one of the earlier requests completes. You should use invalidation only in unexpected circumstances; if you know beforehand that your files will need to be removed from cache frequently, it is recommended that you either implement a versioning system for your files and/or set a short expiration period.

Comment: What if you change the epoch time of the expiration date to like 1 second so it expires quickly enough to generate a new URL with the updated content

Comment: OK, so setting the epoch time to expire quickly doesn't seem to work. I'm not so sure what you are suggesting in your answer, are you saying I should upload a new Amazon S3 object for each version? I'll give you my case, like Twitter, when you follow a user, the users data needs to be updated with the data that they are following you, so I should upload a totally new object with a different file name or some sort of key name aspect? How would I then go to reference this in CloudFront or **know** which one is the newer object based on the key? I'm quite unclear on what you are suggesting.

Comment: @RohanKapur I am suggesting use of a new object with a new file name.  How you would reference the object is really something you would need to work out based on how your app works. I don't know enough about your application and how it interacts with these objects to provide much of a suggestion here. You could certainly store information about the current "version" in the client.  If this is not really static content, but rather content that will change frequently, perhaps S3/Cloudfront is not an appropriate storage medium.

Comment: I know for a fact that S3/CloudFront is appropriate for my apps, it came with a special recommendation from another developer who has successfully built a data intensive app with these services. Think of my app is an EXTREMELY limited and small user base social network. However, I forgot to mention I am using SimpleDB, a key value store similar to MySQL that I use to query objects. So I can add a 'revision' attribute to each SimpleDB item and use the SELECT query to find the newest, thank you for this suggestion. Still wondering if this **is the only** way to do it.

Comment: Also, what will happen if there is a conflict, like Facebook for e.g., if someone 'liked' your 'status' while you are 'uploading a status' at the more or less similar time, there would be a conflict, you would be uploading different revisions, each without either the new status or the new like - how would I deal with that?

Comment: @RohanKapur Sounds like you would need to have some sort of locking system in place.  Are these "objects" just datagrams of some sort or are they binary files. Because if you are using S3 only as a storage medium for non-relational serialized data, you might even want to look into DynamoDb as an alternative. That is really what it is made for and should be a lot more responsive than writing data to S3 since with S3 you have to deal with the issue of eventual consistency.

Comment: They are specifically NSData objects. I can't store my objects on DynamoDB, they are not simple key values, they are actual large data objects (large could be debatable, but still).